# Uniform and absolute convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $$∑\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+x^2}$$  is uniform convergent but not absolute convergent for all real values of x.

By using Dirichlet's theorem I was able to prove uniform convergent but I could not prove regarding absolute convergence.
$|\frac{1}{n+x^2}| < |\frac{1}{n}|$ but $∑\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent so we can't say anything about convergence of $\frac{1}{n+x^2}$. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Limit Comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Or else note that $\frac{1}{n+x^2}\ge \frac{1}{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: thanks a lot. got the solution

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For $x=0$, the absolute series is just the harmonic series.

Suppose $x\neq 0$. Note that $\forall x>0, \exists m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2<mn$. Thus $x^2 < mn$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and

$$ \left|\frac{1}{n+x^2}\right|>\frac{1}{n+mn}=\frac{1}{(m+1)n}.$$

Now you can use the comparison test.